# Java - Hibernate - mappedBy issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Java class with Hibernate annotations that refers to another POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient_Visit_Transaction")
public class PatientVisitTransaction extends Bean {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id")
    List<TransactionNoteDW> notes;
    ....
}
```

The other class is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Transaction_note_dw")
public class TransactionNoteDW extends DateAuditableBean {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "note_seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "transaction_id")
    private String transactionId;
}
```

I am trying to delete a `PatientVisitTransaction` and I get an error:
`mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: TransactionNoteDW.transaction_id in PatientVisitTransaction.notes`.
I guess it is trying to map the `notes` to `transaction_id`.  How do I specify the correct mapping or am I completely off on my assessment?

Comment: There is no mappedBy anywhere in the code you posted. Post the real, and relevant code.

Comment: I dont have any mappedBy annotations in my code.  That is the part that is bizarre.  Hibernate must use some kind of aliasing.  This is the real and relevant code.

Comment: Hmm. Strange indeed. Anyway, @André has the answer. Every time you have an ID of another entity in an entity, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I dont understand.  Is there a blog post you could point me to?

Comment: Read the response you got. Then read the hibernate documentation about bidirectional OneToMany associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to map like this:

```
public class TransactionNoteDW extends DateAuditableBean {
    //....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private PatientVisitTransaction patient;
}
public class PatientVisitTransaction extends Bean {
    //....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient")
    List<TransactionNoteDW> notes;
}
```